# Benefits of reciting different sura

Tags: quran

Assalamualaykum,

I got a question in my mind. We read about many types of benefits of reciting different surah of Quran. Sometimes I got confused about its authentication. Since Quran is a book of knowledge.. so how will it will raise our states in the life and hereafter: 1. Only by the knowledge we gain from Quran and the uses in of these in the life, or
2.By gaining knowledge and application of it..on the other hand reciting it again and again will be very beneficial.

I'm asking this, because there are unlimited things to learn from Quran definitely but also matter of time too.. And since sometimes we see some unauthentic benefits and uses of reciting different types of surah of Quran.. which makes me a bit confused.. an example given below where I found some things doubtful..:

http://www.imamreza.net/eng/imamreza.php?id=3444

The term biddat made me thoughtful about these. I need clarification about these..

Is it true that different surah has different type of benefits?

Jazakallah Khair

Comment: I got another link.. I think its good but need reviews.. please check:

https://www.facebook.com/notes/islam/benefits-of-the-surahs-aayats-of-the-quran-detailed-with-references/204620959552565?ref=nf

Comment: I'm not sure what you're even *asking* here; there's no actual question, you're just expressing confusion about "many types of benefits..." which is just too vague to be readily answerable. I would strongly suggest you check out our help centre page on "[How do I ask a good question?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)" for advice on how to better focus your posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every recitation of Qur'an is a benefit in knowledge and acknowledgement. Why on the day of judgement you will be rewarded for your recital this is a matter on which Allah (swt) is the judge. But the fact that you are reciting it "when done with pure intention" you are validating your belief. The angels are recording your actions and the good djinn that witness your recitation are benefiting from it (insha'Allah) and you are protecting yourself from the Shaytan.

So there are some people out there that says reciting such and such Surah or Ayat helps for various things much like Du'a. Some are based on Knowledge such as a sound hadith. But we should not focus solely on those for we must not neglect the Qu'ran as a whole.